# Batch - What is the difference between CALL and GOTO?

Tags: batch-file, call, goto

I understand both link to labels in the code, but what is the difference?

```
@echo off
:top
echo I love StackOverflow.com
goto :top
```

---

```
@echo off
:top
echo I love StackOverflow.com
call :top
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you ever typed `goto /?` or `call /?` in command prompt?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The example you gave won't really show the difference between the two.

- `goto` - goes to the label.
- `call` - goes to the label and then returns to the caller when the code is complete.

In your example, as your code is never complete, it never returns to the caller.

The only difference you may see, is that the `call` version would eventually crash when the list of "where to return to" will become so big until it "fills up" the memory.

To see how the call command can be used properly: http://ss64.com/nt/call.html

Comment: That link was very useful. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In your example, very little - except the `call` version will eventually crash.

`goto` transfers execution to the label specified; execution continues from that point.

`call` also transfers execution to the label **but** when the processing reaches an `exit` or `end-of-physical-file`, execution is transferred back to the instruction directly after the `call` instruction.

`call` also allows parameters to be passed. As far as the subroutine that is the target of the `call`, its `%1...` are the parameters provided by the `call`, not as provided as command-line parameters to the batch procedure.

You can `call` an external batch or executable, and at the end of *that* called routine, execution will resume with the instruction after the `call`. `goto` will simply execute the target, and completely forget where it was in the original batch

Comment: CALL also establishes a new scope for SETLOCAL / ENDLOCAL commands. ENDLOCAL cannot release variables that were defined before the CALL. Also, there is an implicit ENDLOCAL when returning from a CALL.

Answer (score 0):

with `call` there is a return:

```
for /l %%i in (1,2,10) do call :process %%i
pause
Exit /b

:process
echo subroutine - %1
```